# I am getting the following error for my Xception Model. (GPU turned on)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, keras, deep-learning

I am getting the following error. The model is running for one epoch and then giving the following error. I am using GPU for training (on Kaggle). Images are being loaded with the help of ImageLoader Function.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-512258b05c1b> in <module>
     25                             keras.callbacks.CSVLogger('history.csv')
     26                         ],
---> 27                         verbose = 0
     28 )

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1859         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1860         shuffle=shuffle,
-> 1861         initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   1862 
   1863   def evaluate_generator(self,
InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument:  ValueError: `generator` yielded an element of shape (0,) where an element of shape (None, None, None, None) was expected.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 249, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 620, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 938, in generator_py_func
    (ret_array.shape, expected_shape))

ValueError: `generator` yielded an element of shape (0,) where an element of shape (None, None, None, None) was expected.
```

---

CODE:

```
history = model.fit_generator(
                        imageLoader(train,batch_size),
                        steps_per_epoch = TRAIN_STEPS,
                        epochs = 10,
                        callbacks = [
                            tqdm_callback,
                            lr_callback,
                            ModelCheckpointFull('xception_holdout_model.h5'),
                            keras.callbacks.CSVLogger('history.csv')
                        ],
                        verbose = 0)
```

---

Image Loader is used for loading images

```
def imageLoader(files, batch_size):

L = len(files)

#this line is just to make the generator infinite, keras needs that    
while True:

    batch_start = 0
    batch_end = batch_size
    
    while batch_start < L:
        limit = min(batch_end, L)
        X = imageBatchReader(df[batch_start:limit])
        Y = dataframeBatchReader(df[batch_start:limit])

        yield (X,Y) #a tuple with two numpy arrays with batch_size samples     

        batch_start += batch_size   
        batch_end += batch_size
```

Comment: What is `generator = train_generator`? `imageLoader(train,batch_size)` should be fine itself.

Comment: @Frightera That line was commented in the original code! - I'll edit that out